# Sources for scenarios for Arkham Horror

Tags: arkham-horror

We've been enjoying playing Arkham Horror a lot but it seems to be lacking in narrative. I've read that there are scenarios that add a story element to the game
Is there a good resource for these?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Custom Scenarios were used in 2 Arkham Horror Leagues, organized by Fantasy Flight.

You can find the whole scenarios from the [Arkham Horror Wiki Scenarios Category](http://www.arkhamhorrorwiki.com/Category%3AScenarios) page, along with pdf printouts of each story. There doesn't appear to be a summary of season 1, however.

Compilations of the league scenarios nicely assembled were contributed to the file section on boardgamegeek in pdf format:

[League 1](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/79636/arkham-horror-league-season-1-2008-all-one)

[League 2](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/80110/arkham-horror-league-season-2-2009-all-one)